# Transform position of A to the same position as B

Tags: ios, swift

I have two UIButtons, both are on separate view controllers, what I want to achieve is to move view A to the exact same position as B via a transform.

So something like (pseudo code):

```
let A = UIButton()
let B = UIButton()

let position = A.findAbsolutePositionRelative(to: B)

A.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: position.x, y: position.y)
```

I've tried my way around `UIView.convert` but can't really figure out how to get values that make sense, `A.convert(A.frame.origin, to: nil)` gave `(0.0, 0.0)` for example.

Comment: Do you know where B is? If you do, then what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I have an instance of the button yes, but I don't know where B is positioned relatively to A, that is what I need to figure out 

Comment: so if you have a button on two different view controllers that you are positioning, cant you just set the constraints the same on both buttons and they will be positioned in the same place? or just get button A's x,y position in the view frame and place b at the same position?

Comment: @Scriptable I am trying to achieve a "shared element transition" kind of thing, so I need to transform button B to the same position of A and then animate B to  the correct final position. I could just hard code the position but that won't hold if the buttons move.

Comment: So, you have two `UIViewController` and you have two `UIButton` views placed on each `UIViewController` ? You wish to reposition `UIButton` "A" so that it takes the same position (x,y,w,h) as `UIButton` "B" (which incidentally you do not know where it is on the `UIViewController`)? So that the end product is `UIButton` "B" is no longer visible?

Comment: @Barns exactly, that is what I am trying to do!

Comment: @SamPettersson - confusing... You are showing the view from VC-A, and it has "Button-A"? Then you are what ... segueing to VC-B? Loading VC-B as a childVC and adding its view on top of VC-A's view? And you want "Button-B" to be at the same position "Button-A" was so it looks like it changed from "A" to "B"?

Comment: If you want to do "magic" (àla Keynote) element transitions, you have to read [View Controller Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/animation_and_haptics/view_controller_transitions). The basic concept is that system hands you both controllers and a context and you are responsible to animate the transition. There are several articles on the subject plus at least [one project](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero) you could study and learn from.